# Symfony2 and Twig : apply global filter to all translations

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to always use *nl2br* filter for all translated texts.

My code now is :

```
{% filter nl2br %}
    {% trans %}my_text_to_translate{% endtrans %}
{% endfilter %}
```

And I'd like to have only to write this :

```
{% trans %}my_text_to_translate{% endtrans %}
```

So : how can I enable *nl2br* filter globally ?

Many thanks for your answer :-)

Aurel

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this simple syntaxe in one line: `{{ 'my_text_to_translate'|trans|nl2br }}`

or u can create an extension for twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html

Comment: Thanks for the trick... In fact, I'd like to be able to write something like {{ 'my_text_to_translate'|trans }} and always applying nl2br filter... but if there is no way to do this... Thanks for your answer :-)